# Colocar um nome dependendo do numero do array

Tags: java, array, swing

Imaginemos que tenho 4 variavéis:

> ```
>  - Porto = 1   
>  - Benfica = 2  
>  - Sporting = 3  
>  - Braga = 4
> ```

Tenho este código que me faz um shuffle de números de um array denominado por "arr".

```
Integer[] arr = {1,2,3,4};
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));

     for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {


        }
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

Ao executar o programa imaginemos que obtive o resultado : [1, 3, 2, 4];

Agora que tenho este resultado tenho 4 labels (equipa1, equipa2, equipa3, equipa4);

Quero colocar na label "equipa1" o 1 resultado do array e colocar o nome da equipa correspondente a esse numero neste caso PORTO.

Outro exemplo..

Quero colocar na label "equipa2" o 2 resultado do array, que é 3, então quero colocar nessa label a equipa corresponde ao numero 3, neste caso Sporting..

Podem me explicar como posso fazer isto ?

Para executar o programa tem o código aqui abaixo:

```
public class J2 extends JFrame {
    private JPanel contentPane;
    JLabel equipa1 = new JLabel("");
    JLabel equipa2 = new JLabel("");
    JLabel equipa3 = new JLabel("");
    JLabel equipa4 = new JLabel("");

    public void func(){

        int Porto = 1;
        int Benfica = 2;
        int Sporting = 3;
        int SCVitoria = 4;

        Integer[] arr = {1,2,3,4};
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));

         for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {


            }
            Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));


            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));



    }




    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    J2 frame = new J2();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public J2() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 553, 405);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblJornada = new JLabel("Jornada 1");
        lblJornada.setBounds(61, 11, 80, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblJornada);


        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Gerar Jornada");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

             func();
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(125, 139, 139, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);


        equipa1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        equipa1.setBounds(20, 36, 139, 14);
        contentPane.add(equipa1);


        equipa2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        equipa2.setBounds(169, 36, 139, 14);
        contentPane.add(equipa2);

        equipa3.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        equipa3.setBounds(20, 86, 139, 14);
        contentPane.add(equipa3);


        equipa4.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        equipa4.setBounds(169, 86, 139, 14);
        contentPane.add(equipa4);

    }


}
```

Comment: Label? É interface gráfica? Se sim, você precisa fornecer um **[mcve]** da sua interface para que seja possivel executar o código.

Comment: `Quero colocar na label "equipa2" o 2 resultado do array, que é 3, então quero colocar nessa label a equipa corresponde ao numero 3, neste caso Sporting..` - isso divergiu completamente do resto da pergunta. Se Sporting é 3 , porque ele deveria estar em equipa2?

Comment: Já forneci o código completo. Ele deveria estar na equipa2 porque o sorteio do array é aleatório.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para facilitar a distribuição, crie um array de `JLabel` com o mesmo número de índices do seu array de times, e distribua os times após o *shuffle* conforme abaixo:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class J2 extends JFrame {
    
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JLabel[] equipas = new JLabel[4];
    
    
    public void func() {

        int Porto = 1;
        int Benfica = 2;
        int Sporting = 3;
        int SCVitoria = 4;

        Integer[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        
        
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            equipas[i].setText(String.valueOf(arr[i]));
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new J2().setVisible(true));
    }


    public J2() {
        
        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 553, 405);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblJornada = new JLabel("Jornada 1");
        lblJornada.setBounds(61, 11, 80, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblJornada);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Gerar Jornada");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                func();
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(125, 139, 139, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
        
        JPanel equipaPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));
        
        for(int i = 0; i < equipas.length; i++) {
            equipas[i] =  new JLabel();
            equipas[i].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            equipaPanel.add(equipas[i]);
        }
        
        equipaPanel.setBounds(20, 36, 149, 50);
        contentPane.add(equipaPanel);

    }
}
```

Veja funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Vale ressaltar a recomendação abaixo:

> **Evite usar layout absoluto, a não ser que seja de extrema necessidade e que saiba as consequências disso**, pois layout absoluto dificulta manutenção da tela e faz com que sua aplicação fique com aparência diferente dependendo do monitor e resolução que estiver sendo executada.
>
> Existem vários [**gerenciadores de layouts**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) para que você não tenha que se preocupar com posicionamento ou organização manual de componentes. Sem contar que o uso de layouts faz com que seu código fique mais fácil de dar manutenção do que ficar inserindo um monte de `setbounds`, e caso precise alterar a posição de algum componente, no layout absoluto, vai ter que reposicionar todos manualmente.

Para distribuir os pontos do resultado, eu utilizei `GridLayout`, que te dá liberdade de organizar itens em um layout de grids(parecido com o excel), e como se trata de 4 JLabels em forma quadrática, ele foi a melhor e mais simples opção para o caso.

Quanto ao layout absoluto do painel principal, eu não removi pois teria que reescrever sua tela. Mas fica a recomendação acima.

Comment: Sim sei que vai estourar mas pode exemplificar essa parte de definir a JLabel ?

Comment: @RicardoLopes `labels[indice] = new JLabel();` você pode fazer isso dentro de um laço, e ir posicionando ele na sua tela.

Comment: Peço desculpa mas continuo não entendendo como fazer..

Comment: Pode exemplificar melhor ?

Comment: @RicardoLopes veja a edição.

Comment: Entendo sua recomendação, meu professor só me ensinou na escola como funcionar com layout absoluto e já tentei usar outros e penso que seja demasiado difícil recomenda algum tutorial ?

Comment: @RicardoLopes executou o código da minha resposta? Ele já está funcional. E sobre links, veja a recomendação na resposta, há links da documentação oficial ensinando a mexer em cada um.

Comment: Sim executei o código e está funcional perfeitamente com o que era pretendido.

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução seria você fazer um array com o nome das equipes;

```
String [] nomes_equipes = {"Porto","Benfica","Sporting","Braga"};
```

então, basta acessar a posição (equipe)  do array de nomes ex:

se vc acessar a label "equipa2" o 2 resultado do array, que é 3 e por o nome basta fazer:

```
nomes_equipes[arr[2]]
```

Ele vai acessar a posição 2 do array (que o valor é 3) e a posissão 3 do nomes_equipes (Sporting)